# Is it okay to update coreData store in textFieldShouldReturn?

Tags: ios, core-data, uitextfield, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've read that you should not perform animation in textFieldShouldReturn. CoreData updates cause animations to occur when NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate is implemented. Therefore, is it not advised to update coreData in textFieldShouldReturn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not read that myself (any citation?), but if you're concerned, do your updates in `textFieldDidEndEditing:` instead.